# Theorem 3.55 in Baby Rudin: How to make sense of the proof?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

Here's Theorem 3.55 in the book *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Walter Rudin, 3rd edition.

> If $\sum a_n$ is a series of complex numbers which converges absolutely, then every rearrangement of $\sum a_n$ converges, and they all converge to the same sum.

Now here's Rudin's proof.

> Let $\sum a_n^\prime$ be a rearrangement, with partial sums $s_n^\prime$. Given $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists an integer $N$ such that $m \geq n \geq N$ implies $$ \sum_{i =n}^m \left\vert a_i \right\vert \leq \varepsilon.$$ [This relation Rudin calls (26). ] Now choose $p$ such that the integers $1, 2, \ldots, N$ are all contained in the set $k_1, k_2, \ldots, k_p$ (we use the notation of Definition 3.52). Then if $n > p$, the numbers $a_1, \ldots, a_N$ will cancel in the difference $s_n - s_n^\prime$, so that $\left\vert s_n - s_n^\prime \right\vert \leq \varepsilon$, by (26). Hence $\left\{ s_n^\prime \right\}$ converges to the same sum as $\left\{ s_n \right\}$.

And, finally, here's Rudin's Definition 3.52.

> Let $\left\{ k_n \right\}$, $n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$, be a sequence in which every positive integer appears once and only once (that is, $\left\{ k_n \right\}$ is a 1-1 function from $J$ onto $J$, in the notation of Definition 2.2). Putting $$ a_n^\prime = a_n \ \ \ (n= 1, 2, 3, \ldots),$$ 
>   we say that $\sum a_n^\prime$ is a *rearrangement* of $\sum a_n$.

And, for the sake of completeness, Rudin uses the symbol $J$ to denote the set of natural numbers.

Now my question is, how does Rudin's relation (26) give the conclusion that $\left\vert s_n - s_n^\prime \right\vert \leq \varepsilon$ if $n > p$?

Here's how I have been able to understand the proof.

> Given that $\sum \left\vert a_n \right\vert$ converges, we can conclude that $\sum a_n$ converges too. Let 
>   $$s = \sum_{n =1 }^\infty a_n.$$
>   Let $s_n$, $(n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots)$, be the partial sums of $\sum a_n$. Then $$s = \lim_{n \to \infty} s_n.$$
>   Now let $\sum a_n^\prime$ be a rearrangement of $\sum a_n$, and let $s_n^\prime$, $(n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots)$, be the partial sums of $\sum a_n^\prime$.
>
> We show that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} s_n^\prime = s$$ as well. Now as $s_n \to s$ as $n \to \infty$, so, given $\varepsilon > 0$, we can find a natural number $N_1$ such that $$ \left\vert s_n - s \right\vert < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n > N_1$.
>
> Now as $\sum \left\vert a_n \right\vert$ converges, so we can find a natural number $N_2$ such that $$ \sum_{i =n}^m \left\vert a_i \right\vert < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$$ for all $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $m \geq n \geq N_2$. So we can conclude that $$\left\vert \sum_{i=n}^m a_i \right\vert < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$$ for all $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $m \geq n \geq N_2$.
>
> Now let $N = \max \left\{ N_1, N_2 \right\}$. Then, for all $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $m \geq n > N$, we have $$ \left\vert s_n - s \right\vert < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$$ and also $$\left\vert \sum_{i=n}^m a_i \right\vert < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}.$$
>
> Now let $p$ be a natural number such that the integers $1, 2, \ldots, N$ are all contained in the set $\left\{ k_1, \ldots, k_p \right\}$. Then, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n > p$, we see that the difference $s_n - s_n^\prime$ is a sum of some finitely many terms of the sequence $\left(  a_{N+1}, a_{N+2}, a_{N+3}, \ldots\right)$, and therefore $$\left\vert s_n - s_n^\prime \right\vert < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}. $$
>
> So if $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is such that $n > \max \{ N, p \}$, then we have $$ \left\vert s_n - s_n^\prime \right\vert < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$$ and also $$\left\vert s_n - s \right\vert < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}.$$ Therefore, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n > \max \{ N, p \}$, we have 
>   $$ \left\vert s_n^\prime - s \right\vert \leq \left\vert s_n^\prime - s_n \right\vert + \left\vert s_n - s \right\vert < \varepsilon,$$ from which it follows that $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} s_n^\prime = s$$ also.

Is my understanding of the proof of Theorem 3.55 in Baby Rudin correct? If so, then is my version the same as Rudin's? If not, where have I erred?

And, if my proof is also correct but differs from Rudin's, can anybody here please fill in the details in Rudin's original proof for me? Thanks.

Comment: Looks valid, I didn't spot any errors. (I didn't carefully scrutinize it, so I may have overlooked some small glitch.) See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/523979/theorem-3-55-rudin-rearrangement-and-convergence) for how I think Rudin intended the proof.

Answer (score 2):

$$N \leq p < n.$$
$$s_n = a_1 + \cdots + a_N + a_{N+1} + \cdots + a_n.$$
$$s'_n = a_{k_1} + \cdots + a_{k_N} + \cdots + a_{k_p} + a_{k_{p+1}} + \cdots + a_{k_n}.$$
$$\{1, \cdots, N\} \subset \{1, \cdots, n\}.$$
$$\{1, \cdots, N\} \subset \{k_1, \cdots, k_p\} \subset \{k_1, \cdots, k_n\}.$$
$$\{1,\cdots,N\}\subset\{k_1,\cdots,k_n\}\cap\{1,\cdots,n\}.$$
$$T:=(\{k_1,\cdots,k_n\}\cup\{1,\cdots,n\})-(\{k_1,\cdots,k_n\}\cap\{1,\cdots,n\}).$$
$$T \cap \{1, \cdots, N\} = \emptyset.$$
$$\text{If } i \in T, \text{ then } i \geq N+1.$$
$$|s_n - s'_n| \leq \sum_{i \in T} |a_i| \leq \sum_{i=N+1}^{\max{T}} |a_i| \leq \epsilon.$$

Answer (score 1):

**Warm-up.**

By Theorem 3.45, if a series converges absolutely, then the original series converges as well. Furthermore $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = 0$.

If a series converges, then for such series Cauchy criteria is true, that is Theorem 3.22. There exists $N$ such that if $m \ge n \ge N$ implies

$$ \left| \sum_{k=n}^{m} a_k \right| < \epsilon $$

In the above expression indexes $m, n$ are all finite despite the fact that any series contains infinite number of terms.

**Abstract for Theorem 3.55**

In order to prove our theorem we have to apply to the definition of a limit (a bit modified for two series). We have to show that by Definition 3.1 for any arbitrary $\epsilon >0$ there exists $N$ such that $n > N$ implies $d(a_n, b_n) < \epsilon$. In our case $a_n$ and $b_n$ are the series $s_n$ and $s'_n$.

Again, all we need to find is this $N$ such that 
$$ n \ge N \qquad \text{implies} \qquad |s_n - s'_n| < \epsilon $$

In our case it is $p$, index of the second series.

First, for the first series we have to find such $N$ so that

$$ m \ge k \ge N \qquad \text{implies} \qquad \left| \sum_{n=k}^{m} a_n \right| < \frac{\epsilon}{2} $$

Then, for this $N$ found for the first original series, in the rearranged series we find index $p$ such that the first $p$ terms of the second series include the first $N$ terms of the first series.

Why do we do this? We do this because we need the difference between these two series to be arbitrary small.

We have $$ \left|\underbrace{s'_n}_\text{$\le \frac{\epsilon}{2}$, sum of remaining terms} \quad - \quad \underbrace{s_n}_\text{$\le \frac{\epsilon}{2}$, sum of remaining terms} \right| < \epsilon $$

In the above expression the first N terms of $a_n$ cancel out, and both remaining bits are less than $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

**To re-iterate**, index $p$ of $s'_n$ is what we need for the arbitrary difference to be less than epsilon.